# How to install extension on server in yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have an website running on server.

I want to use graph extension to show some reports.

How do install extension on server?

Locally I can use cmd for that, do I need to download project install extension and upload it again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable SSH access on your server.

[DigitalOcean SSH tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu) - here you can find some helpful informations about SSH connection.

If you connect by SSH, navigate to project directory and use `composer install` or `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a command line access to your server and so cannot use composer directly, I would recommend to do prepare the code locally in a 'deploy' folder and then copy the whole folder content, including the vendor directory, to the server. I assume that you can use composer locally, so that you can install the extension regularely . And I assume that the local machine and the server does differ to much (PHP version, other settings).

Installing the yii2-extension does mean: if you install it with `composer install` Yii gets prepared so that you can use the code like any other code in your application. Installing the extension creates an entry in `vendor/yiisoft/extension.php which gets evaluated each time the application gets loaded.